# 2nd thread for loop not executing in Java8

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java threads. I'm solving a question where I've been given a `Solution.java` class which executes 3 java threads from 3 different `Thread extended classes` that I've wrote. Following is the way that the predefined class is using to start threads:

```
public class Solution {
        public static final int[] threadArray = new int[300];
        public static volatile String i = 0+"";
    public boolean test() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Task1 task1 = new Task1();
        Task2 task2 = new Task2();
        Task3 task3 = new Task3();
        Thread task2Thread = new Thread(task2);
        Thread task3Thread = new Thread(task3);
        task1.start();
        task2Thread.start();
        task1.join();
        task2Thread.join();
        task3Thread.start();
        int first = Task1.a+Task2.a;
        int containsSecondThread = Task1.a;
        String oneAndTwo = "";
        String sizeOfTask1 = "";
        for(int i=0;i<first;i++)
        {
            oneAndTwo += threadArray[i]+" ";
        }
        for(int i=0;i<containsSecondThread;i++)
        {
            sizeOfTask1 += threadArray[i]+" ";
        }
        int begOfTask3 = Task3.beg;
        String checkingString = "";
        for(int i=begOfTask3;i<threadArray.length;i++)
        {
            checkingString += i + " ";
        }
        String task3String = "";
        for(int j = begOfTask3;j<threadArray.length;j++)
        {
            task3String += threadArray[j]+" ";
        }
        if((!oneAndTwo.contains(begOfTask3+"") && sizeOfTask1.contains(Task2.beg+"")) && task3String.equals(checkingString))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            Solution solution = new Solution();
            int one = sc.nextInt();
            Task1.a = one;
            Task1.beg = 0;
            int two = sc.nextInt();
            Task2.a = two;
            Task2.beg = one;
            int three = sc.nextInt();
            Task3.a = three;
            Task3.beg = one+two;
            System.out.print(solution.test());
    }
}
```

Aim of the question is to run `task1` and `task2` simultaneously. And then run `task3` after complete execution of both `task1` and `task2`. Following is my thread classes implementation:

```
class Task1 extends Thread{    
    public static int a;
    public static int beg;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int k=beg;k<a;k++){
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(Solution.i);
            Solution.threadArray[idx] = k;
            idx++;
            Solution.i = Integer.toString(idx);
        }
    }
    
}

class Task2 implements Runnable{
    public static int a;
    public static int beg;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int k=beg;k<a;k++){
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(Solution.i);
            Solution.threadArray[idx] = k;
            idx++;
            Solution.i = Integer.toString(idx);
        }        
    }
    
}

class Task3 implements Runnable{
    public static int a;
    public static int beg;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int k=beg;k<300;k++){
            int idx = Integer.parseInt(Solution.i);
            Solution.threadArray[idx] = k;
            idx++;
            Solution.i = Integer.toString(idx);
        }        
    }
    
}
```

The issue is that only `task1` is executing. No other thread is running and I don't understand why. I'll be really glad if someone could help me out with this one.

Edit: I've added the complete `Solution.java` class. Also I've changed a little bit of code in classes implemented by me. I'm sorry for not testing it earlier, but all the threads are running. Only issue is that `for` loop in second thread is not running. I used `System.out.println` inside and outside the `for` loop and that's how I got to know it.

Answer (score 0):

What evidence do you have that only one thread is executing?

What I'd expect from analysing your code is that all three threads should execute, but `task1` and `task2` should finish almost instantly (probably in less than 1ms), while `task3` should take longer but still finish quickly (probably in less than 1 sec).

The reason for the different run-times is that `task1` and `task2` both have a loop relying on static `int` fields which are never given a value, so those fields have the default value of `0`. Where you have lines like `for(int k=beg;k<a;k++)`, but `beg` and `a` are both `0`, those loops exit immediately without iterating.
With `task3`, you compare the loop counter to the constant `300` so it should run 300 iterations.

It might help if you include the rest of the `Solution.java` class you were given, since what you have included clearly isn't complete.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right that all the threads are running. But both `beg` and `a` are getting initialized in the main function of `Solution` class. I have edited my post. I hope this might give you a clear view.